# Bilinear forms and skew symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $B:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a symmetric bilinear form. Let $f\in Aut(V)$ such that $B(f(u),v)=-B(u,f(v))$ for all $u,v\in V$.

How to prove that the matrix of $f$ with respect to some basis is skew-symmetric? Do we have to have orthogonal basis in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ is definite positive, let $(e_1,...,e_n)$ be an orhonormal basis, $f(e_i)=\sum_jB(f(e_i),e_j)e_j=\sum_j a_{ij}e_j$, we have, $B(f(e_i),e_j)+B(e_i,f(e_j))=0$. This is equivalent to saying that $a_{ij}+a_{ji}=0$ which is equivalent to saying that the matrix of $f$ in $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: orthogonal with respect to what?

Comment: Orthonormal in respect of $B$